# Grails 2.5.0 endpoints located sans application context

Tags: grails

I am upgrading an existing Grails 2.2.4 app to 2.5.0.

For some reason, endpoints whose URLs included the app context in 2.2.4 no longer include the app context in 2.5.0.

e.g., for app context = `app`, old endpoint in 2.2.4 was:

`/app/a/b/c`

but in 2.5.0 is now:

`/a/b/c`

I have tried many things to fix this, including:

- in application.properties:

  - `app.name=app`
  - `app.context=/app`
- in Config.groovy, for testing on localhost:8080:

  - `grails.app.context = "/${appName}"`
  - `grails.serverURL = http://localhost:8080` and `grails.serverURL = http://localhost:8080/${appName}`, at different times
  - `app.grails.serverURL = http://localhost:8080` and `app.grails.serverURL = http://localhost:8080/${appName}`, at different times

I've verified that `"${appName}" == 'app'`.

I have upgraded all of the plugins to the newest version, but I'm continuing to use the resources plugin instead of the asset-pipeline plugin.

I am not using scaffolding.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UrlMappings.groovy` contained some mappings with `(parseRequest:true)`, which is no longer supported by Grails.  Removing that fixed it.